# Selecting values of a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a Column which have string values in my PostgreSQL table.

The string looks like this:

```
'192.168.1.1-mike.landline,192.136.152-sam.phone,192.364.1.0-main-phone'
```

Based on the string how can I select the last most value before the comma starts. i.e. 192.364.1.0-main-phone

I tried to look it up but no luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `regexp_replace().`

```
select regexp_replace('192.168.1.1-mike.landline,192.136.152-sam.phone,192.364.1.0-main-phone', '.*,', '');

     regexp_replace     
------------------------
 192.364.1.0-main-phone
(1 row)
```

Read about [POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in the documentation.

---

Update. You can trim commas ending a string with the function [`rtrim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-string.html), e.g.:

```
select rtrim('some_string,', ',')

    rtrim    
-------------
 some_string
(1 row)
```

so your query may look like this:

```
select regexp_replace(rtrim(the_string, ','), '.*,', '');
```

Comment: Thank you @klin for answering my question. Can you please help me with one more problem. The problem is that in some of my data my strings ends with a comma for an example '192.364.1.0-main-phone,'. How can I select the last value in that case